# Python, sqlite3, проблемы с выводом данных при определенном параметре (дате)

Tags: python, sqlite

такой вопрос: почему при выборе текущей даты не выводит данные при запросе? Если больше, меньше -- работает, а вот когда хочу сравнить с текущей датой, то результата не дает.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('DB.db')

def sql_fetch(con):

cursorObj = con.cursor()

cursorObj.execute('SELECT NUMBER, EQUIPMENT FROM Sheet1 where DATE = current_date')

rows = cursorObj.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    print(row)

sql_fetch(con)
```

Это как-то связано с форматом даты в базе данных (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)? В БД у меня, к примеру, 2022-08-21 00:00:00, и из-за этого времени мы друг друга не понимаем.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен в каком формате вы передаете в базу параметр времени, но оно должно быть в формате TimeStamp, а там то что у него минуты и секунды не слишком важно. Например, можно примерно так:

```
cursorObj.execute('SELECT NUMBER, EQUIPMENT FROM Sheet1 where DATE = ?', (datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Вместо ? - будут подставляться значения из кортежа

Comment: Excel таблицу превратил в базу данных, сначала был тип данных TimeStamp, я сделал DateTime.
Сделал по вашему примеру, пока ругается, ищу гуглю что не так (import datetime прописал, почему-то в ответах на ошибку пишут, что надо "," поставить после datetime.datetime.now).

Ваш пример использовал при типе данных TimeStamp также.

Comment: datetime.datetime.now() занес в квадратные скобки. Ошибки не вылазят. Но и данные не выходят (при прочем условии <, > работает).

Comment: То есть если пустое условие, то работает? Можно попробовать now() обрезать до даты вида день месяц год

Comment: В общем проблема со временем, убрал из БД значения 00:00:00 и все заработало. Долго, правда, доходил до этого)

Comment: Но все равно, либо как-то из excel переводить без времени, либо в самом sqlite убирать время. Пока ищу варианты.